# MongoDB date sorting is not working

Tags: mongodb, sorting, date

I'm using `mongo 2.4.10`. Date stores in DB in `ISO format` (`'2015-02-16T09:00:00+0500'`). Also datetime field has index.

But when I try to sort by date - DB returns wrong sort data. I think it should take into account timezone at the end of datetime string or not? How force it to work with timezones?

```
db.appointments.find().sort({datetime: -1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54db6562266aa1250e000006"), "created_at" : "2015-02-11 16:21:22", "datetime" : "2015-02-16T11:00:00+0400", "doctor_id" : ObjectId("5490149f266aa13a6f000115"), "patient_id" : ObjectId("54901307266aa1816f000001"), "status" : "confirmed", "updated_at" : "2015-02-11T16:25:51+0200", "visitreasons" : [  ObjectId("54cb6738266aa14a71000018") ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54d0e460266aa1564f000003"), "created_at" : "2015-01-31 15:46:05", "datetime" : "2015-02-16T09:00:00+0500", "doctor_id" : ObjectId("549031ca266aa16b7600009c"), "patient_id" : ObjectId("54901307266aa1816f000002"), "status" : "Pending", "updated_at" : "2015-01-31 15:46:05", "visitreasons" : [  ObjectId("54cb6738266aa14a71000018") ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54ccdc9d266aa1093c000003"), "created_at" : "2015-01-31 15:46:05", "datetime" : "2015-02-16T05:00:00+0000", "doctor_id" : ObjectId("549031ca266aa16b7600009c"), "patient_id" : ObjectId("54901307266aa1816f000001"), "status" : "Pending", "updated_at" : "2015-02-26T11:05:43+0200", "visitreasons" : [  ObjectId("54cb6738266aa14a71000018") ] }
```

Comment: Could you post your query, or at least the sorting part?

Comment: I've changed the topic text

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287493/how-to-deal-with-the-timezone-issue-when-storing-dates-in-utc-using-mongod

Comment: ZeMoon, not mine case

Comment: You're not storing date types; you are storing string representations of dates. Fix the data so you are storing actual dates and sorts will work correctly: `db.test.insert({ "t" : ISODate("2015-02-26T16:04:17.474Z") })`, not `db.test.insert({ "t" : "2015-02-26T16:04:17.474Z" })`

Comment: wdberkeley, thank you I'll try this