# Meteor/MongoDB: Sorting collection by date is returning incorrect results

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

I am attempting to sort a MongoDB collection based on the user's choice (name, client, date etc). For name and client, the sorting works fine because it sorts by string, however, when sorting by the date field, the results are not accurate (which is strange because changing it to ascending or descending does actually change the results, but it is not being returned in the correct order.

Here is the sorting code:

```
let sort_order = {};
//columnSortType is date field and columnSortDirection is either 1 or -1
sort_order[instance.state.get("columnSortType")] = instance.state.get("columnSortDirection");
if (instance.state.get("showAllServers")) {
   return Servers.find({}, {sort: sort_order});
}
```

Here are sample results to give you a better idea of the messed up order (just returning the date field). This is sorting by ascending order. Sorting by descending simply flips the below list:

2016-05-25
2016-05-25
2016-05-25
2016-04-23
2016-04-23
2016-04-23
2016-03-23
2016-03-23
2016-03-23
2016-07-21
2016-07-21
2016-07-21

I came across [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738488/mongodb-date-sorting-is-not-working) which seemed to be having similar issues to me, however, my date fields are definitely in ISODate format when they are saved to the database. For example, 2016-04-23 looks like this: ISODate("2016-04-23T04:00:00Z"). This makes me think that this might be a timezone issue or an internal clock issue, though running it locally on two separate computers still returns the same results.

**UPDATE- Resolved**:

I figured out the reason that the sorting appeared to be in the incorrect order (it actually was returning correctly, it just visually did not appear to be that way). I was using moment.js to format the date on the client side which meant that if an object previously had a blank date, moment.js would fill in said date with the current date. This is why some of the dates seemed to be in the incorrect order as the sort was not taking into account the newly added dates--which were not being saved to the database.

Comment: Can you create a simple test case that reproduces it?

Comment: are you sorting by multiple columns? Maybe, there is some other column that takes precedence over date.

Comment: @MasterAM Yes, I have tried this with new date values and still get the same result.

Comment: Well, I was implying that you would share it with us :)

Comment: @Vijay No, the query I've written above is all I have which only has the one parameter to sort by. Also, I run the sort directly from the meteor mongo shell and get the same result.

Comment: @MasterAM Oh, ok! Let me do a quick one.

Comment: @Vijay Figured it out! Just posted an update.

Comment: @MasterAM Figured it out! Just posted an update.

Comment: You should probably post the update as an answer or delete the question.

Comment: @MasterAM Done and thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason that the sorting appeared to be in the incorrect order (it actually was returning correctly, it just visually did not appear to be that way). I was using moment.js to format the date on the client side which meant that if an object previously had a blank date, moment.js would fill in said date with the current date. This is why some of the dates seemed to be in the incorrect order as the sort was not taking into account the newly added dates--which were not being saved to the database.