# MongoDB dayOfMonth timezone

Tags: mongodb

I'm using `$dayOfMonth` in an aggregation, however this is using the UTC date as it's stored mongo and giving different results as it *should* be in ETC (-0500).  Is there an alternative way to get the day of the month in an aggregation that would allow to use the desired timezone?

Comment: This could possibly help: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852095/how-to-agregate-by-year-month-day-on-a-different-timezone)
or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287493/how-to-deal-with-the-timezone-issue-when-storing-dates-in-utc-using-mongod)

Comment: Yes, actually that works.  First I had to project the new date that uses add, then use $dayOfMonth against that in another project.

Comment: cool! glad it worked out.