# MongoDB is storing date objects in local time, not UTC

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

In MongoDB, a date is getting stored like this: "2019-11-16T01:17:50.446+00:00".  That is the local time (PST).  How can I make sure that the date is stored in UTC?

Comment: 2019-11-16T01:17:50.446+00:00 => +00:00 so you azre  on utc!

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to this and I don't understand.  Isn't there supposed to be an 8 hour time difference?

Comment: See these useful posts: [mongodb-date-in-timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135851/mongodb-date-in-timezone) _and_ [mongodb-aggregate-convert-date-to-another-timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914737/mongodb-aggregate-convert-date-to-another-timezone).